# Entity Framework- Complex joins into several tables, returning Table1 based on a condition on Table2

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression

I already have something functional, but I am attempting to abstract it further. Right now, the only way I can get this done is through Linq's SQL syntax. As an example of what I mean:

```
query = from t1 in query
join t2 in joinedTable on t1.JoinProperty equals t2.JoinProperty
where t1.FilterProperty > t2.FilterProperty
select t1;
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is abstract the selection of "t1.JoinProperty", since the rest of this join structure is identical for everything in my system. I know that with the .Join method, it would be simple to abstract it:

```
<Expression<Func<<t1Type, joinPropertyType>>> abstractedSelector = (t1 => t1.JoinProperty);
query.Join(joinedTable, abstractedSelector, joinedTable.JoinProperty, (t1, t2) => /*something*/);
```

the problem is in that "where" clause. With this syntax, how do I keep a handle on both t1 and t2 so that I can filter further on the related properties, WITHOUT enumerating the results? I know I can use "(t1, t2) => new {T1=t1, T2=t2}", but my understanding is that dropping the entities onto objects like this is going to enumerate the data.

Is there some override on the Join method or something that'll let me do what I want? Or is there some way to get the abstracted property selection into the Linq SQL syntax?

EDIT: With some testing, it looks like the anonymous types in the .Join function does NOT enumerate the data like I expected it would. Using this, it looks like I can accomplish what I'd like to accomplish. If there's a similar solution for the Linq SQL syntax, though, I'd still love to see it.

Comment: Do you have access to the database to create a view instead?

Comment: I do, but it's a relatively simple SQL query in the end, and needs to be applied to more-or-less every entity in our system, with the ONLY difference being the selection onto that join property. Our current approach is to create stored procedures for each query to do this logic, but it's a lot of overhead and generally messy. Views would be even worse, IMO. That's why I'm trying to isolate the one difference and generalize everything else, and I've already proven that EF is capable of generating the query I want it to.

Comment: Do you have to use the .Join function, or could you use navigation properties instead?

Comment: At the moment, there is no navigation property, and it wouldn't be feasible to make a direct one. I'd have to go "t1.P.T2" if anything. And even so, it doesn't solve the abstraction problem, where I want to generally define "t1 --> ???? --> P" and be able to place this definition in a generalized structure that will apply the filtering consistently across each resource.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with LINQ Query (Comprehension) syntax and must use LINQ Method (lambda) syntax.